# PyCharm reclamando da variável local

Tags: python, pycharm

Seguinte, a seguir tenho um código feito em Python 3.7.2 bem simples e básico (estou aprendendo ainda e quis treinar um pouco fazendo uma rotina de treino de academia). O programa funciona normalmente, porém o PyCharm está reclamando (marcando a palavra de amarelo) da variável local "**cor**". 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso eu atribua qualquer valor (desde string a um número) à essa variável antes do comando **for in**, o PyCharm para de reclamar, porém eu queria saber o porquê disso. Alguém pode me ajudar pf? *(Esta é minha 1ª pergunta no stackoverflow)*

**Aqui está o código para quem quiser copiar e verificá-lo:**

```
dias = 'Segunda, Terça, Quarta, Quinta, Sexta, Sábado, Domingo'
dias = dias.split(', ')

treino = 'TRÍCEPS/PEITO, PERNAS/ABS, BÍCEPS/COSTAS'
treino = treino.split(', ')

cont = 0   # CONTADOR MÚSCULO

cores = {'tri': '\033[1;34m', 'bic': '\033[1;36m', 'per': '\033[1;31m'}  # 
PALETA DE CORES

for c in range(0, 7):

    print('\033[1;30m+---+---+---+---+---+---+')

    # DEFINE A COR DA STRING DO MÚSCULO TREINADO
    if cont == 0:
        cor = cores['tri']
    elif cont == 1:
        cor = cores['per']
    elif cont == 2:
        cor = cores['bic']

    # QUARTA-FEIRA, DIA DE DESCANSO
    if c == 2:           
        print(f'|\033[1;33m{dias[c<7}\033[1;30m|\033[1;35m{"descanso":^15}
\033[1;30m|')
        cont = 1

    # DIAS NORMAIS, NOS QUAIS HÁ TREINO
    else:
        print(f'|\033[1;33m{dias[c]:<7}\033[1;30m|{cor} 
{treino[cont]:^15}\033[1;30m|')

    cont += 1

    # RESETA O CONTADOR DOS MÚSCULOS
    if cont == 3:
        cont = 0
print('\033[1;30m+---+---+---+---+---+---+')
```

Comment: Sempre digite o seu código ao invés de apenas colar imagens mostrando o mesmo. Isso possibilita que outras pessoas possam reproduzir seu código e verificá-lo.

Comment: Você possui um `if` que define o valor de `cor`. Se `cont` for diferente de 0, 1 e 2, qual será o valor de `cor`?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss O cont nunca será diferente de 0, 1 e 2, pois quando ele passa a valer 3, o programa atribui o valor 0 à ele.

Comment: @Cadu Desculpa, obrigado pela recomendação! Já adicionei o código.

Comment: @EduardoCoêlho então não precisa de `elif cont == 2`, se não é 0 ou 1, necessariamente será 2; pode usar o `else`.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Muito obrigado! Deu certo agora, eu tinha pensado nisso na hora de criar o programa, porém não achei que isto seria um problema para o PyCharm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta você posicionar o *mouse* sobre a notificação que aparecerá a mensagem do que a IDE estranhou:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em tradução livre, o nome `cor` pode não estar definido. Isto é um **aviso**, não um **erro**. O aviso está mais para "Cuidado! Algo **pode** estar errado".

Isso porque você fez:

```
if cont == 0:
    cor = cores['tri']
elif cont == 1:
    cor = cores['per']
elif cont == 2:
    cor = cores['bic']
```

E nas outras condições? Quando `cont` for 3, a variável `cor` não será definida. O PyCharm está te avisando isso justamente porque pode ser uma situação que você esqueceu de tratar, podendo ocasionar algum erro mais grave na aplicação.

Você comentou que `cont` nunca será diferente de 0, 1 ou 2, então para quê verificar os 3 valores? Se não é 0 ou 1, com certeza será 2, então basta fazer:

```
if cont == 0:
    cor = cores['tri']
elif cont == 1:
    cor = cores['per']
else:
    cor = cores['bic']
```

Mais simples que isso, você pode definir um dicionário para fazer esse mapeamento:

```
cor = {0: cores['tri'], 1: cores['per'], 2: cores['bic']}.get(cont, None)
```

Basicamente é criado o dicionário:

```
{
    0: cores['tri'],
    1: cores['per'],
    2: cores['bic']
}
```

E acessada a posição `cont`. Se a posição não existir, será retornado o valor `None`.